# Background image not displaying on GitHub pages?

Tags: html, css

so I have a website at (http://zoid-studios.github.io/) but for some reason the background which should be centred bottom below the title isn't there?

Here's my css:

```
.top-section
    height: 100vh
    background-image: url(../images/background.svg)
    background-size: 100%
    background-position: center bottom
    background-repeat: no-repeat
```

Any help? The background shows when viewed locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename seems to be `Background.svg` and not `background.svg`.

Answer (score 1):

URIs in CSS are mostly case sensitive. Your actual image name is `Background.svg` (capital `B`), whereas in the CSS it's `background.svg`. That's the problem.

> All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e., [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent), except for parts that are not under the control of CSS. For example, the **case-sensitivity** of values of the HTML attributes "id" and "class", of font names, and of **URIs** lies outside the scope of this specification. Note in particular that element names are case-insensitive in HTML, but case-sensitive in XML. -[W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)